# Reference ng-model parent from directive

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, pug

So I have the following Jade template:

```
  div(ng-controller="TodoListController", ng-init="setTodos(...)")
      div(ng-repeat="todo in todos")
          span(contenteditable="true", ng-model="todo.description"){{ todo.description }}
```

And I'm defining the following directive for the `contenteditable` attribute:

```
TodoModule.directive 'contenteditable', ->
  return {} =
    restrict : 'A'
    require: '?ngModel'
    link : (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) ->
      read = ->
        ngModel.$setViewValue elem.html()
      elem.on 'blur', ->
        scope.$apply read
```

And here's the relevant part of `TodoListController`:

```
TodoModule.controller 'TodoListController', ($scope, $http) ->
  $scope.update = (todo) ->
    $http.put "/todo/#{todo._id}.json", todo
      .success (data) ->
        if !data.todo
          alert JSON.stringify data
```

The problem here is that I have really no idea how to reference the `todo` object from within the `contenteditable` link function so that I may call `scope.update(todo)` in the contenteditable's blur event. Is this somehow obtainable from ngModel as a parent perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with, I'm not entirely confident it's the best way though so I won't mark answered yet.

I've added a `update-on-blur` attribute to my jade template passing the parent `scope.update(todo)` function:

```
      span(contenteditable, update-on-blur="update(todo)", ng-model="todo.description"){{ todo.description }}
```

And added an isolate scope to my directive and then called the new function within the blur trigger:

```
TodoModule.directive 'contenteditable', ->
  return {} =
    restrict : 'A'
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope:
      updateOnBlur: '&'
    link : (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) ->
      console.log scope
      read = ->
        ngModel.$setViewValue elem.html()

      elem.on 'blur', ->
        scope.$apply read
        scope.updateOnBlur()
```